# Adding and consuming web reference using wsdl definition in asp.net client

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

First let me say that I'm new to web services and though I have google'd and watched tutorials I"m still having issues figuring out why I cannot consume the service. I'm not exactly sure how to ask the question I'm trying to lay it out nicely. If I've missed some needed info I'll be happy to add it to the question. Thanks for your time.

I was given a service reference to consume of https://demo.cashlinc.com/IntegrationService/Service.svc to consume.

I then proceeded to perform the following steps from visual studio...

1. From the client (consumer) application RMB > Add Service Reference...[image]
2. From the Add Service UI, Address: https://demo.cashlinc.com/IntegrationService/Service.svc?wsdl , namespace = DivDatService
   [image]
3. The service reference structure is like this...

   [image]
4. Now here is the part where I'm fumbling...
   There is for example a method `GetPaymentProfiles`...now that I've added the web reference how do I call the method?
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: you need to create an instance of the web service that you are trying to consume for example ` var divDat = new DivDatService()` then use `var mystring = dviDat.GetPmtProfiles();` there are a ton of free video's as well as other tutorials online in regards to how to consume a webservice in C#.NEt

Comment: you need to also create a public method that returns a List<T> as well so this would be what we call `Method Overload` you have one method that returns a string `GetPmtProfiles` and you show in another method `GetPmtProfiles` that it takes 3 input params and returns a List<T>

Comment: I would recommend you to create **web reference** instead of **service reference**. pls take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)